# How to use curl in C#

Tags: c#, curl, mono

I have a problem with https request on old version of mono, because it dont support TLS 1.2. I decided to use CURL. I tried to use it via Process, but it is very slow. So I need help with it. Maybe there are another way or dll?

Comment: i'm not sure about your use-case. But have you checked if the HttpClient in the System.Net Namespace covers your need?

Comment: There were attempts like https://github.com/stil/CurlThin to wrap libcurl in C#, but it is incomplete. You probably can get some ideas from it and then start your own adventure. But overall, new versions of Mono or simply .NET Core should be your primary option if possible.

Comment: Can you explain the context that you're using it because it's not clear why it would be prohibitively slow. Obviously spawning a process is non-trivial overhead but I would think the cost would be amortized over the relatively high cost of making an HTTP request.